# How to handle SelectedIndexOutOfRange using try and catch?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, gridview, exception, datagridview

I have a gridview and a delete button in **Asp.net**. Delete will only work when a row is selected from the gridview. I want to prevent the website from crashing by making it more user friendly. So if the user does not select a row and press delete it would notify them through a label. Would it be **SelectedVlue** or **SelectedRow**?

This is what I attempted:

```
if (GridView1.SelectedValue == null)
        {

            int i = GridView1.SelectedIndex;
            myDataSet.Tables["Records"].Rows[i].Delete();

            GridView1.DataSource = myDataSet;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            Label5.Text = "Oops, please select a row";
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `SelectedRow` is `null` when no row is selected. You can also use `SelectedIndex != -1`. But you are checking for `== null` instead of `!= null` anyway what is the wrong logic.

```
if (GridView1.SelectedRow != null)
{
    // ...
}
else
{
    Label5.Text = "Oops, please select a row";
}
```

or

```
if (GridView1.SelectedIndex != -1)
{
    // ...
}
else
{
    Label5.Text = "Oops, please select a row";
}
```

Comment: Oh yes, I was. But you have to wait certain amount of time to accept the answer Don't worry :)

Comment: You answered too quickly, and the stackoverflow didnt like it haha

Answer (score 0):

You should replace your code with this:

```
        if (GridView1.SelectedRow != null && GridView1.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            int i = GridView1.SelectedIndex;
            myDataSet.Tables["Records"].Rows[i].Delete();

            GridView1.DataSource = myDataSet;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            Label5.Text = "Oops, please select a row";
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(GridView.SelectedRow != null)
{
    // proceed with your action
}
else
{    
    Label5.Text = "Oops, please select a row";
}
```